# How to get bootstrap-select drop down value in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-select

I have a drop down with `name="country1"` where I am getting dynamic data through query inside it. Now, I want to get the value of in my alert box but it's not working right now. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

code:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick">
    <div class="dropdown-menu open">
        <div class="bs-actionsbox">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-block">
                <button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-select-all btn btn-default">Select All</button>
                <button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-deselect-all btn btn-default">Deselect All</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner state1" role="menu">
            <?php
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('states');
                $this->db->where('country_id','101');
                $sql = $this->db->get();
                $result = $sql->result_array();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
            ?>
                    <li data-original-index="0">
                        <a tabindex="0" data-tokens="null">
                            <span class="text"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select name="country1" class="bootstrap-select" title="India:State" multiple="" data-actions-box="true" tabindex="-98">
        <?php
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('states');
            $this->db->where('country_id','101');
            $sql1 = $this->db->get();
            $result1 = $sql1->result_array();
            foreach($result1 as $row1)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['name']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.state1 li').click(function(){
            state = $(this).text();
            alert(state);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't you use var state?

Comment: looks like both li and select box has same values and you are asking to get values on click of li, is that correct?

Comment: yes, it is @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: When I click on `select` dropdown then it shows me data in `<ul>` list form. @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: your code looks fine. check for any console error and if you can re-create the problem on code snippet then we can take a look at it